# After upgrading to Eclipse Luna, WindowTester is unable to identify the view menu in the 'Problems' view

Tags: eclipse-plugin, window-tester

Last week we have upgraded to Eclipse Luna and lots of WindowTester test cases started to fail. The reason behind this is that the 'WT is unable to find the Pull Down Menu in the 'Problems' view (small down arrow icon) and we are getting the below exception. Is there a work around.

The Exception I get is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.windowtester.runtime.swt.locator.eclipse.PullDownMenuItemLocator$1.call(PullDownMenuItemLocator.java:126)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.swt.locator.eclipse.PullDownMenuItemLocator$1.call(PullDownMenuItemLocator.java:1)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.swt.internal.drivers.MenuDriver.resolveAndSelect0(MenuDriver.java:83)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.swt.internal.drivers.MenuDriver.resolveAndSelect(MenuDriver.java:57)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.swt.locator.eclipse.PullDownMenuItemLocator.click(PullDownMenuItemLocator.java:124)
    at com.windowtester.internal.runtime.selector.ClickHelper.doClick(ClickHelper.java:181)
    at com.windowtester.internal.runtime.selector.ClickHelper.click(ClickHelper.java:69)
    at com.windowtester.internal.runtime.UIContextCommon.click(UIContextCommon.java:147)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.swt.internal.UIContextSWT.click(UIContextSWT.java:334)
    at com.windowtester.internal.runtime.UIContextCommon.click(UIContextCommon.java:140)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.swt.internal.UIContextSWT.click(UIContextSWT.java:342)
    at com.windowtester.internal.runtime.UIContextCommon.click(UIContextCommon.java:133)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.swt.internal.UIContextSWT.click(UIContextSWT.java:304)
    at com.sample.ExportLogEntriesTest.testSaveLogEntries(ExportLogEntriesTest.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.common.UITestCaseCommon.access$0(UITestCaseCommon.java:1)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.common.UITestCaseCommon$2.run(UITestCaseCommon.java:140)
    at com.windowtester.runtime.common.UITestCaseCommon$3.run(UITestCaseCommon.java:161)
    at com.windowtester.internal.runtime.junit.core.SequenceRunner$1.run(SequenceRunner.java:50)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the issues with WindowTester and Eclipse 4.4 in this branch:

https://github.com/fredg02/windowtester/tree/tychoWIP_e44

I will try to do a release soon. In the meantime, you can always build it from source yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at it

Comment: Release is now available here: https://github.com/fredg02/windowtester/releases/tag/6.1.2-beta1-e44x